# I can't run ganache in my terminal, even though it's installed

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, ganache

It seems I have a path error, I can see proof the package installed, and I've tried it both globally and local, tried both with and w/o the -cli suffix, but zshell keeps complaining command not found

```
dr_frankenmiller@Bryans-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm install ganache-cli
```

> npm WARN deprecated ganache-cli@6.12.2: ganache-cli is now ganache; visit https://trfl.io/g7 for details
>
> added 1 package, and audited 102 packages in 11s
>
> 2 packages are looking for funding
> run `npm fund` for details
>
> 9 vulnerabilities (8 moderate, 1 high)
>
> To address issues that do not require attention, run:
> npm audit fix
>
> To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
> npm audit fix --force
>
> Run `npm audit` for details.

```
dr_frankenmiller@Bryans-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm  ls --depth=0      
dr_frankenmiller@ /Users/dr_frankenmiller
└── ganache-cli@6.12.2

dr_frankenmiller@Bryans-MacBook-Pro ~ % ganache-cli
```

> zsh: command not found: ganache-cli

I might have done something bad, using a `sudo rm -rf node_modules` command to uninstall the package, was that dangerous to do? I reinstalled it globally and then tried running it again,  and then zshell started complaining I wasn't authorized to run ganache. I tried the command `sudo ganache`, it asked me for password, and then responded again that command not found.

Can someone help me get back on track with my tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Ganache-CLI's](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli-archive#installation) instructions, it should be installed with:

```
npm install ganache-cli -g
```

I'd recommend installing the latest Ganache version rather than installing Ganache-CLI, though. Ganache-CLI is deprecated. Use

```
npm uninstall ganache-cli && npm install ganache -g
```

Ganache v7.0.0 and onward can be used in the CLI as well as programatically.

On another note, I ***strongly*** recommend against using `sudo` when installing anything via npm. This can give untrusted code the ability to run as admin on your system. Definitely a big security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up on difficulties I was having, I ended up using yarn to download and run ganache (MINUS the -cli suffix, -cli suffix now deprecated), yarn install ganache --global to install and then yarn ganache to run (no -cli necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I found the solution for my specific use case. The bug came about when I was attempting to run a brownie deployment script. Run npm uninstall ganache-cli then run yarn global add ganache. Worked like a charm.